# Separate interface orientations per view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on an iPhone app with a UINavigationController interface and there I want all views to ONLY allow default portrait rotation except for one. I know I can return 'NO' in the shouldAutoRotate method but basically when I am in the view that does allow rotation and go back to the previous view, the other views are then stuck in landscape as well. Any ideas?

Comment: try setting [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]; in ViewWillDisappear when returning from landscape view to portrait view

Comment: This makes the simulator go back to portrait, but not the view :-/

Comment: as rahulvyas said, u need to set the orientation to portrait in previousview which need to be portrait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change status bar orientation when you go back to previous view.

Comment: See my above comment to SriPriya

Comment: you also need to return the orientation in the method shouldAutoRotate

Comment: Would someone be able to elaborate on this? I am seeing the simulator change to portrait when calling `setStatusBarOrientation:`, but not the view itself. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @BryanIrace you need to override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in your view controller. By the way only ViewControllers will notified about the orientation changes not the view. I mean those classes whose super class is UIView will not get notification about orientation changes you need to manually pass this info to your view's object